# Can't find package modules/methods if I import the whole package

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

While I was building a Python package and I came across the necessity of calling the whole package (`import tools`) but I could not find the package's modules. This was the result when I called `dir(tools)`:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

In other hand when I tried to import modules directly (`from tools import A, B`) it worked.

What can be causing it?

This is the simplified package structure:

```
tools/
    setup.py
    tools/
        __init__.py
        A.py
        B.py
```

Package was generated using cookiecutter's audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage template

Comment: Have you tried to put a __init__.py in the top tools folder? Python sees packages via the __init__.py so I think thats the reason why you only can import like `from tools import A,B` because python findes them via the __init__.py try to create a __init__.py in the same directory as setup.py and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

`import Tools` will expect Tools to be a class name in the Tools module

you can try

`from tools import *`

to import every class in that module